# How would I alter the SQL that Linq-to-Nhibernate generates for specific columns?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-4

To take advantage of Full text indexing on MariaDB 10, I need to use this new "MATCH AGAINST" syntax in the sql string.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

I think it would be really cool if, for certain columns only, I could override linq-to-nhibernate to change the sql it generates when I use

```
.Where(x => FullTextIndexedStringProperty.Contains("Some word")).ToList().
```

Who can give me some general directions on how to get started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get you a very simple `MATCH ... AGAINST` clause. If you want to get more complex (more arguments, specifying the search modifier), you'll have to make some bigger changes. Hopefully this will get you started though:

1. Create a new dialect and register a simple `MATCH (...) AGAINST (...)` function:

   ```
   public class CustomMySQLDialect : MySQLDialect
   {
       public CustomMySQLDialect()
       {
           this.RegisterFunction(
               "matchagainst",
               new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                   NHibernateUtil.Boolean,
                   "match (?1) against (?2)"));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a static extension method on `string` that you'll use in LINQ statements:

   ```
   public static class LinqExtensions
   {
       public static bool MatchAgainst(this string source, string against)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a new LINQ to HQL generator class that associates the method with the SQL function we registered in the custom dialect:

   ```
   public class MatchAgainstGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
   {
       public MatchAgainstGenerator()
       {
           this.SupportedMethods = new[]
           {
               ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => LinqExtensions.MatchAgainst(null, null))
           };
       }

       public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(
           MethodInfo method,
           System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject,
           ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
           HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder,
           IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
       {

           return treeBuilder.BooleanMethodCall(
               "matchagainst",
               arguments.Select(visitor.Visit).Cast<HqlExpression>());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a custom LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry:

   ```
   public class MyLinqToHqlRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
   {
       public MyLinqToHqlRegistry()
       {
          var generator = new MatchAgainstGenerator();
          RegisterGenerator(typeof(LinqExtensions).GetMethod("MatchAgainst"), generator);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Use your custom dialect, and Linq to HQL registry either in your cfg.xml file or in code:

   ```
   var cfg = new Configuration()
       .DataBaseIntegration(db =>
   {
       db.Dialect<CustomMySQLDialect>();
   })
   .LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<MyLinqToHqlRegistry>();
   ```
6. *Finally*, use your extension method in a LINQ-to-NHibernate query:

   ```
   session.Query<Article>()
       .Where(a => a.Body.MatchAgainst("configured"))
       .ToList()
       .Dump();
   ```

   This will generate SQL that looks like this:

   ```sql
   select 
       userquery_0_.Id as Id51_, 
       userquery_0_.Title as Title51_, 
       userquery_0_.Body as Body51_ 
   from 
       articles userquery_0_ 
   where 
       match (userquery_0_.Body) against ('configured');
   ```

Again, this won't help if you have more complicated requirements. But hopefully this is at least a good starting point.

In case anyone is curious about how to make this support more complex scenarios, here are the problems I think you'd run into:

- Separating the arguments to `MATCH` from those to `AGAINST`.
- Registering a custom SQL function with NHibernate that can take an arbitrary number of arguments in different places
- Creating the correct HQL even after solving the two issues above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check out your tutorials later.

Comment: Also, much better idea to just make a new function MatchAgainst() in linq instead of overriding contains.

Comment: Yeah I hope there's enough of us out there to keep it alive for the next little while

Comment: Can you edit the missing step #4 into your answer that I have posted below, I can't get it past the editors.

Comment: @IsaacBolinger: Sorry about that, I'm not sure how I left that out. Looks like it got past.

Comment: It didn't get past, did it? I don't see it in there. I'm using your code now. Added the search bar yesterday. I'll improve it as I need to.

Comment: @IsaacBolinger: Argh, sorry--Updated the answer