# How to implement "Firebird" "Similar to" with linq nhibernate in c#

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

How to implement "Firebird" "Similar to" keyword with LINQ to NHibernate. I need it to do search with Regular expression.
Thanks.

In fact I want to do this kind of things

```
from entity in Session.Query<Entity>()
where entity.field.SimilarTo("[0-9]*")
```

to find for example numeric rows.
SQL generated :

```
select ....
from entity e0
where e0.field similar to '[0-9]*'
```

Comment: So, being a member for over a year, I expect that you have read the stackoverflow guidelines? Such as this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What did you try? in which case show it, otherwise, go try.. come back when you've tried and got a specific question

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t precise. I hope is now clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very helpful example on stackoverflow [How would I alter the SQL that Linq-to-Nhibernate generates for specific columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915373/how-would-i-alter-the-sql-that-linq-to-nhibernate-generates-for-specific-columns)

```
public class CustomFirebirdSQLDialect : FirebirdDialect
{
    public CustomFirebirdSQLDialect()
    {
        this.RegisterFunction("similar to",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                NHibernateUtil.Boolean,
                "?1 similar to ?2"));
    }
}

public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static bool SimilarTo(this string source, string regex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SimilarToGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public SimilarToGenerator()
    {
        this.SupportedMethods = new[] { ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => LinqExtensions.SimilarTo(null, null)) };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(
        MethodInfo method,
        Expression targetObject,
        ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
        HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder,
        IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {

        return treeBuilder.BooleanMethodCall(
            "similar to",
            arguments.Select(visitor.Visit).Cast<HqlExpression>());
    }
}

public class MyLinqToHqlRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public MyLinqToHqlRegistry()
    {
        RegisterGenerator(typeof(LinqExtensions).GetMethod("SimilarTo"), new SimilarToGenerator());
    }
}
```

and add this to nhibernate config

```
config.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
{
    db.Dialect<CustomFirebirdSQLDialect>();
})
.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<MyLinqToHqlRegistry>();
```

Hope this help some body else.